# Xcode error: Failed to prepare device for development

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, beta, xcode12

I have updated to Xcode 12.3 beta. device version is 14.2, but Xcode complaining:

> Errors were encountered while preparing your device for development. Please check the Devices and Simulators Window.
>
> Failed to prepare device for development

iPhone directly connected to MacBook.
I have tried all mumbo jumbos on the web. but no success any idea?

[image]

> Unable to prepare DEVICE for development
>
> Please check the connection to the device, and review all errors in the Devices and Simulators window.

Comment: Did the mumbo jumbos include restarting your device and making sure it has enough free space?

Comment: 120 Gb available

Comment: I've had a couple of similar issues, but they've all gone away after some combination of macOS/iOS restarts and/or disconnecting/connecting the device. I assume you've already tried those. No other ideas, sorry!

Comment: P.S. If you're jailbroken, try it in jailed state. It could be the developer profile isn't trusted.

Comment: I got this error on Xcode 13.1 when my iPhone Xs MAX updated to iOS 15.3.1. Updating to Xcode 13.2.1 solved the problem. (Restarting the device and my Mac, disconnecting/reconnecting, deleting the device, deleting the app, etc. all did not work for me.) I think Xcode has to stay "ahead" of your iOS version. It would be nice if the error message told you to update Xcode!

Comment: @ZacharyDrake agreed. Until they improve the error code, this page lists the compatibility between Xcode, iOS, and MacOS: https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/

Answer (score 664, accepted):

**A simple phone restart will fix it**

I have had to come back to this SO question twice in the past couple weeks. First time, I did have to update my Xcode and iOS versions, which fixed the issue. Now, the issue has returned, but there are no updates. I tried disconnecting and reconnecting my phone from my laptop, but to no avail.

What fixed it the second time was merely restarting my phone. I am curious if that would have fixed it the first time too, without needing to have updated.

I know this is just echoing the other answers here, but at the very least, I would recommend just starting with a simple phone restart and seeing if that fixes your problem. Here is the specific screenshot that I encountered, in case yours is the same (pro tip: you can open up the "Devices and Simulators" window by going to Window -> Devices and Simulators `shift-command-2`).

[image: Errors were encountered while preparing your device for development. Please check the Devices and Simulators Window]

Comment: Restarting didn't quite work for me (started happening after updating iOS device to 14.4 18D52), but the below comment suggesting to uninstall, clean the build folder & repair did: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64974291/xcode-12-3-beta-failed-to-prepare-device-for-development#comment115811665_65088414

Comment: This worked for me, with the additional step of having to have Xcode re-trust the device. I just followed the prompt on the device and entered my device passcode.

Comment: Restarting helped for Xcode 12.4 (12D4E) with iPhone iOS 14.4.1 (18D61). A message will appear before running the app on the device: "[...] Copying cache files from device [...]", but this is fine.

Comment: as Sean Goudarzi says make sure you turn off personal hotspot and reconnect without the personal hotspot on

Comment: Restarting device not working for me, Xcode 13, ios 15

Comment: Restarting the device does not work for me, latest Xcode 13.2.1. Since latest iOS update (15.4.1). WARNING! THINK TWICE about updating your test phones to latest iOS. This has permanently broken this for me. Can't run to any iOS 15.4.1 devices. Already filed Apple radar: https://feedbackassistant.apple.com/feedback/9989952

Comment: Not sure if this helps someone but doing `flutter doctor` gives you 

> [✓] Connected device (2 available)
    ! Error: Failed to prepare the device for development. This operation can fail if the version of the OS on the device is incompatible with the
      installed version of Xcode. You may also need to restart your Mac and device in order to correctly detect compatibility. (code 806)

Comment: Restarting both device and Mac did not work for me

Comment: Changing USB port worked for me :D

Answer (score 246):

This error shows because of iPhone OS version is not supported by Xcode that's why this warning popped up, so check which max ios version is supported by Xcode which you are using.

In my case, the Xcode version is 13.1 and my iOS version is 15.4 so what I did, First downloaded device support version 15.4 from [here](https://github.com/mspvirajpatel/Xcode_Developer_Disk_Images/releases) (Download according to your device version) and added this to my Xcode.

steps to add the file in Xcode:-

1. Go to Applications > Right click on Xcode and Select Show Package Contents > Contents > Developer > Platforms > iPhoneOS.platform > DeviceSupport.
2. Extract your device support file to DeviceSupport Folder.
3. Restart Xcode and unplug and plug in your device.

Comment: This worked perfectly fine for me, Im on Xcode(V 13.1), my iPhone(OS 15.4.1) -- I downloaded device support version 15.4 from the link you provided -- It worked like a magic ---  Thank you very much

Comment: Worked like a charm.  It's mind-blowing that such a common task (I am a developer and just updated my iPhone) requires this much manual labor!  Apparently, Apple doesn't give a damn about developers... sigh...

Comment: Finally it worked! I'm so annoyed that my perfectly up-to-date XCode didn't have the device support for my perfectly up-to-date iPhone! It only had support for iOS up until 15.2, which is very silly, in my opinion.

Comment: great answer!. worked for me. xcode 13.1 and iOS 15.4.1

Comment: Dear user @Rajni gujarati your answer worked like a swiss watch. I've had this issue with XCode 13.2.1 and iOS 15.4.1. Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: This is correct solution and explanation. Although updating the XCode (which includes the latest iOS version support) seems like the easier and better option.

Comment: Worked for me too, but I can't believe XCode is this dumb. Why can't it just pull the files itself and setup unless I'm missing something here.

Comment: Nice one. None of the other suggestions worked (restarted everything multiple times, deleted derived data, unpaired device, etc.), but by doing this manual process XCode showed "Fetching Debug Symbols" when I restarted after adding the device support. I thought XCode did this automatically... but I guess not. Sigh.

Comment: Thank you! This worked for Xcode 13.3 and iOS 15.6

Comment: Yes, this did for me. On. aside note even after this you might get a screen that says "iphone not ready, preparing device" in this case just wait, in my case I just waited like 3 minutes, but around the web some people had to wait around 10 minutes, so just a heads up. Great answer though.

Comment: Works perfectly for iOS 16.2 missing on my MacOS Ventura 13.1!
Thanks!!

Comment: work with Xcode Version 13.3.1 and iOS 16.2

Comment: Works with Xcode 14.2 and iOS 16.4.1

Comment: This should be marked as correct answer, makes perfect sense and the solution worked instantly

Comment: I would add to restart Xcode, unplug and replug device, and restart Mac.

Comment: This solution worked for me with Xcode 14.2 on macOS Monterey 12.6.8 and iOS 16.5

Comment: This is the real answer, worked for iOS 16.6

Comment: This solution partially worked for me. I was finding disk image for ios 15.8 but was not available at your link , so I searched on Internet and it showed me to use 15.5 and rename it as 15.8

Answer (score 91):

Exact same problem here, this solved the issue for me:

- Delete the app from the phone
- Clean the Build Folder with: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>
- Delete derived data
- Unpair device (from <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd> window)
- Disconnect iPhone
- Restart iPhone
- Restart Mac
- Trust

After this, it worked for me.

Comment: Helped. Thank you. My device is on iOS 14.2. With XCode 12.2 I could not run the app on the device. With XCode 12.3 and your steps I can run the app.

Comment: All I did was clean build folder, restart both Mac and phone, then it worked

Comment: Why tho why tho why? Thanks it worked for me.

Comment: The only steps necessary are these three.

|| Delete the app from the phone
|| ⌘ + shift + K -> clean build folder
|| Unpair device (from cmd + shift + 2 window)

Comment: this solution works with 12.3 GM also, Thanks!

Comment: ^ I also only had to replicate the steps outlined by @MarcusZiadé above

Comment: Thx, I worked after i deleted the app and clean the build folder, on iOS `14.4` and XCode `12.5 beta`

Comment: "Unpair device" helped me.

Comment: Add also "Faith" to this.

Comment: First two did the job for me.  Xcode 12.4 + iOS 14.4.2

Comment: The most important point on the list is Trust/Faith, lol

Comment: Not sure how to react to the answer: it lists multiple steps, only a few of which may actually help. In my case, it was deleting the old version of my app.

Comment: Nice and thorough answer. Didn't work for me, but the it made me think it must be something with the project. So if I open another project, and the connect the phone all is well. I can the go back to my original project and run - yay.
Devices and simulators window is still complaining but I can work around it...

Comment: Having this same problem with Xcode 13.2.1 and iOS 15.4 on an iPhone 8 device. Anyone have a solution to this problem with these versions? I tried the solution in this answer in a few different combinations. I haven't fixed the problem.

Comment: Thank you mate! Had the exact same problem with Xcode 13.4.1 and iPhone 13 Pro Max iOS 15.4.1, and after spending 1 hour of looking for answers, your steps worked perfectly!

Comment: Always ok but suddenly came out this problem and do not know why. Restart mac worked. iOS 14.0.1 + macOS 12.5.

Answer (score 34):

I restarted my iPhone(14.2); now both Xcode 12.3 beta and 12.2 can run app on my device.

Answer (score 27):

I could not get the phone to authorize until I had the paired Apple Watch trust the computer as well.
A more helpful error message could be imagined.

Both the iPhone and the paired Apple Watch must trust the computer before the phone can be successfully prepared for development.

Comment: You've saved so many hours!! Simply not having the watch on my wrist made me not see that prompt...

Comment: Same problem here. Using XCode 12.5. This got rid of the message that it can't prepare the device for development. I didn't check my apple watch for a request for pairing. Now I have the problem that my phone iOS is 14.6 and XCode does not have the device support files. Don't know where to find them.

Comment: Thank you! I'd spent hours trying every other possible solution but this is the one that worked.

Comment: Lol. Same here, they should think about adding some sound chime or something

Answer (score 12):

If u are looking this because, your `ios 15.7` device (*latest for iPdas at the moment*) show this error on `xcode 14.0` (*latest at the moment*) it is a bug related with the xcode version.

Check [Here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14-release-notes).

[image]

**Update**

This issue is fixed in Xcode `14.0.1`

Comment: Could you add details of how you know it's xcode 14 bug?

Comment: @Jona Thread: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/714388 — Quote: `Xcode 14.0.1 Release Candidate is now available for download, addressing this issue. If you continue to see issues using Xcode 14.0.1 with iOS 15.7, please let us know through Feedback Assistant, and post the FB numbers here.` — Download page for Xcode 14.0.1 RC: https://developer.apple.com/download/applications/ — It's working for me; Xcode is building to iOS 15.7 now.

Comment: I have iOS 15.7. When i updated from xcode 14.0 to 14.0.1 - it works for me! thanks o lot for advice

Answer (score 10):

In my case was to keep the iOS version with my Xcode version in sync.

```
Xcode 12.3 with iOS 14.3
```

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/ lists the version compatibility.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks [Matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt) for hint:
Updating device iOS to 12.3 beta fixed the problem.

if you updated you iOS to latest beta version, you should also use latest Xcode beta version.

Comment: why do apple always have them in reverse???? releasing dev tools first is a better arrangement

Answer (score 8):

What worked for me was to go to Xcode Devices and Simulators window, then ...

- right click on the Connected device, and select "Show Provisioning Profiles" menu item, then delete all the provisioning profiles,
- right click on the Connected device, and select "Unpair Device" menu item
- Unplug and reboot the phone

Comment: Disclaimer: Not only did this not work for me but also nuked all the other provisioned apps on the device (obviously). Don't try this unless you're prepared for that to possibly happen.

Comment: Sorry to hear that ... but yeah that would delete all your developer provisioned apps. Given that this solution is a 100 to 1 compared to the accepted resolution, YMMW. A simple reboot did not help me, so I had to go nuclear. Looks like a few others had to as well.

Comment: Unpair Device , worked for me

Answer (score 8):

I tried most suggestions here. The only thing that ended up working was unpairing my phone in Xcode then unpairing my apple watch from my iPhone. Connects just fine now. iOS (14.3) Xcode (12.3)

Comment: Same thing here. Rebooting device and laptop, re-pairing phone, and even upgrading Xcode and iOS did not work.

Comment: same here with ios 14.4 and xcode 12.4.
thanks a lot for this suggestion!

Comment: I don't think there is a way to go back to a previous version in iPhone. Is there?

Answer (score 5):

Exact the same problem with Xcode 12.3 beta ; for me, just have to:
Disconnect the phone
Restart the phone still on ios14.2

Answer (score 5):

**Solution:** Update your Xcode to a newer release date than your iOS Release Date.

Comment: I had this problem on Xcode 13.1 with my iPhone Xs Max on 15.3.1. The unplugging/plugging back in and restarting the the phone and my Mac (OS 11.6.4 (20G417)) did not solve my problem. I updated Xcode to 13.2.1 and the problem went away.

Answer (score 3):

**-> data cable off**

**-> data cable on**

and it **works** :)

Comment: I don't understand, please elaborate

Comment: I imagine people have tried this, prior to Googling this error..

Answer (score 3):

just Clean the Build Folder with: ⌘ + shift + K

Comment: The most unhelpful solution ever!

Comment: are you try it ?

Comment: No, I am John. :-p , I had tried it eventually.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this problem when using the iPhone's personal hotspot on my Mac. The fix was to disconnect the phone from the computer, then disconnect from the personal hotspot and reconnect again. Apparently this makes the mac use the wifi hotspot (and not the usb hotspot on the iPhone, which messes things up when debugging).

Comment: You don't even have to be *using* the personal hotspot, just having it turned on on the phone causes this error. THANKS - this has been bugging me for weeks.

Answer (score 2):

As many people mentioned/suggested, restarting my iPhone solved the problem.

My setups are: Catalina 10.15.7, Android Studio 4.0, Flutter 2.01,and Xcode 12.4.

Comment: solved problem for me, simple restart phone :)

Answer (score 2):

I think having an apple watch paired to your iphone causes some issues.

I had trusted from my apple watch, but was still having this issue. Unparing my apple watch from my iphone was the only thing that worked for me:

- unpair apple watch from iphone
- unpair iphone from xcode

Restart both, and don't pair apple watch until the iphone is paired.

and, if you have any other problems, and are using flutter, run `flutter doctor`, and ensure you have cocoapods installed.

and once again, if Flutter issues, [follow the details here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63993212/26510) to ensure you have your signing setup correctly

also, if things aren't working, then do a `flutter clean`, and then try again.

Answer (score 2):

Updating Xcode is a fix because old versions of Xcode can't talk to new versions of iOS (see https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/ for compatibility).

If you're stuck on an old version of Xcode you can use something like https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport or https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport which installs the newer device support files into older versions of Xcode.

Answer (score 2):

For me, the fix was going into `Settings` --> `developer` --> `Clear Trusted Computers`, then re-trusting your computer while Xcode is open.

Let Xcode do its thing with the "new" device and once its done I no longer saw the `Failed to prepare device for development` message, and was able to run successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved my issue removing the iPhone cable and putting it back.

Answer (score 1):

1. cmd + shift + 2
2. Click the red cross to check error detail
3. In most cases, the error message shows your xcode supported iOS version is lower than your iPhone's iOS version.
4. Update your xcode.

Answer (score 1):

If other answers don't work, try updating Xcode.

For me I was using Xcode 14.0.0. The release notes for 14.0.1 say

> This update fixes an issue that prevents development with devices running iOS 15.7.

Indeed my phone is on iOS 15.7.

Answer (score 1):

Go to:

1. [Devices and Simulators Window](`Cmd` + `Shift` + `2`):
2. Look for a drop-down labeled `Show run destination`, It might be set to `Never`:

- Change it to `Always` or `Automatic`.

That should fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing from the above listed helped me and also I have encountered this problem when the app was removed for a while. But turning off the phone for 10 mins solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My Current Setting and Versions:
XCode 12.4 and iOS 14.4

- I had to update XCode since my iOS was updated. This fixed the compiler error in Unity and then the same message popped up during deployment. All I did was disconnect/re-connect.

Comment: It seems update in this version isn't mandatory, i'm using iOS 14.4 and Xcode 12.3 and it works fine. Maybe just need device support.

Answer (score 0):

This solved the issue for me:

- Delete the app from the phone
- Clean the Build Folder with: <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>K</kbd>
- Unpair device <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>2</kbd>
- Disconnect iPhone

Comment: This did not resolve the problem but good to know the shortcut for Unpairing devices

Answer (score 0):

Restarting the iPad works for me every time!

Answer (score 0):

We encountered this error and determined it was due to a damaged iPhone cable. New cable, problem solved.

Comment: Not sure why someone downvoted you, we had the exact same problem, Device showed up on the list but we couldn't run the app and had this error message "Failed to Prepare...". Switched the cable to the exact same port and we saw the popup "Trust this Device" on the phone and XCode ran fine.

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't sure why I was downvoted either. The issue is real and I verified that the cable was actually damaged before posting my answer. I knew the answer could be helpful to others since a damaged cable can still mount a device and behave normally in certain ways, making it an elusive problem. In my case I could still transfer files from the device with other applications, so I didn't immediately think that the source of the issue with Xcode could be partial damage to the cable.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to unpair the phone from Xcode's `Devices and Simulators` screen and then tap `Trust` when connecting it to the computer to make my Watch work with Xcode

Answer (score 0):

In my case, after updating iPhone to a newer iOS version then got this issue.

The solution is needed to **update XCode to the latest version** and everything is ok.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the iOs Deployment target to "iOs 15". Then it worked. After that, I just set it back to iOS 12, and everything keeps working.

Answer (score 0):

If nothing worked for you, try the below steps.

- **Update the Xcode**
- **Update the iOS version**
- **Connect mac and iPhone to the same wifi**

Answer (score 0):

I got it resolved today by upgrading OS on my Mac to 12.3.1 and Xcode to 13.3.1 as well as restarting and re-connecting devices couple of times.

Answer (score 0):

## If all else fails

Make sure you have enabled **developer mode** on the device!

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/enabling-developer-mode-on-a-device

In my case, I upgraded iOS 15.6 to iOS 16.0.1 and **Developer Mode was disabled after update** that causes error `Failed to prepare device for development`.

Answer (score -1):

In my case solution was:

- **General** settings on phone device
- Profiles & Device Management
- Open developer app and click on **Trust**

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error message after updating Xcode to 12.4. I have disconnected and reconnected iPad. Then, I have waited for 1 or 2 minutes for Xcode to process device's cache files. Finally, I could run my application in device.

Answer (score -1):

For me, it was a "Trust" issue, where in the past, after the long build process, finally XCode would try to install on the phone, and by then it would have forgotten that I selected to "trust" the mac (on the phone), and give some error message that I needed to disconnect and reconnect the phone to run the app on it. This was with earlier versions of Xcode.

This time, with Xcode 12.3, that error message didn't show up, but instead, got this unhelpful generic error message. I had selected to trust the Mac earlier, but I think because of the long build process, and the machine went to sleep during that time, then the Mac "forgot" that I had chosen to trust it. The next time, I disconnected and reconnected the phone, selected "trust" again, and babysat the phone to stay awake while the re-build was happening. Then it worked.

I didn't have to reboot the phone or mac or even restart Xcode.

Answer (score -1):

I found that if the device is in "Low Power Mode" it would result in this error. So just deactivate it in your settings.

Answer (score -1):

Running Xcode 12.4 and iOS 14.4 on an iPhone Xs and ran into same issue today. First time I've seen it. I wanted to echo what many of the other contributors here have already indicated; rebooting the iOS device did the trick.

Comment: Hey Daniel! Welcome to SO! I think answers like this are generally frowned upon, and would be better suited to a comment on the existing answer if you found that answer helpful, along with an upvote on the answer if your permissions allow (I understand there are some limitations for new accounts). More upvotes help good answers get recognised more than anything else :)

Answer (score -1):

[image: devices and simulators view]

Me help is set mark radio "connect via network" (on the top right devices and simulators menu)

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same on my iPhone running `iOS 15.0` while trying to run my app from `Xcode 13.0`, killing the UBS demon helped me, **no restart was required**.

```
sudo killall -STOP -c usbd
```

More from [Apple Developer Forum](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/133106).

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue and tried all the other suggested fixes:

- Cleared Derived Data
- Xcode clean/restart
- Removed paired device
- Restart device
- Restart Mac
- Trust the computer on both Device and Apple Watch again

In the end the only thing that worked for me was to update my paired Apple Watch Series 3 to the latest OS version.

Answer (score -1):

After Mac and iPhone rebooting, if you have Apple Watch - wear them and input trust code or even reboot them.

Answer (score -1):

1. Check your Max OS X version and eventually update.
2. After this check AppStore on Mac for XCode updates.
3. Then check iOS device for iOS updates.

I have spend some time restarting device and mac before I notice that iOS is updating automatically while Mac OS does not. You will not see XCode updates on older Mac OS X.

Answer (score -2):

The steps below, work for me :D

- Delete the app from the phone
- Clean the Build Folder with: ⌘ + shift + K
- Delete derived data
- Unpair device (from ⌘ + shift + 2 window)
- Disconnect iPhone
- Restart iPhone
- Restart Mac
- Trust

Thanks !!!

Answer (score -2):

The current iOS version requires XCode 14.3 which can only be installed on macOS 13+. This means that for example a 2016 MacBook Pro without compatibility can no longer install the current version of XCode and therefore not deploy to the iPhone.

Answer (score -2):

To everyone still wondering how to solve this issue on ios 16+

- Update your macOS to the latest version
- Update your XCode version to the latest version (only available after updating macOS)
- open xcode and plugin your ios device
- it should appear now under privacy tab on your iphone

Answer (score -3):

What helped me after phone restart is, on the phone:

1. Go to settings
2. Developer
3. Forget trusted devices (its the first button)
4. Reconnect the phone to the mac
5. Click trust on the phone
6. Exit settings(otherwise it will say that your phone is busy)
7. Click that play button in XCode

Comment: where can you see "Developer" inside settings page of your iphone?
where can you see "Forget trusted devices" inside settings page of your iphone?