# Error: Errors were encountered while preparing your device for development. Please check the Devices and Simulators Window. (code -1)

Tags: iphone, flutter, device

i want to run my flutter app on my iphone from android studio, but Android studio doesn't read my phone on the devices tab while I clearly see it active on my mac.

while running flutter doctor I get this message:

```
 Error: Errors were encountered while preparing your device for
      development. Please check the Devices and Simulators Window.  (code -1)
```

and I have restarted my phone, the issue still persists, what do i do?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65088414/7316824)

And try always `flutter devices` to see if your device was detected by flutter

Comment: did not work, my ios version is 14.7 and my Xcode is 12.5. it still says OS version unsupported on Xcode

Comment: Try to update your Xcode to Xcode 13 beta version

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem after an iOS update.
The solution is:

- On your iPhone, go to Settings > Privacy & Security > Developer Mode and switch it on.
- Your device will restart and after the restart it will ask you again if you want to switch on the developer mode, hit yes and the android studio should recognize your iPhone.

Hope this helps.