# Unable to prepare XYZ’s iPhone for development

Tags: ios, xcode, build

A few days ago, I was able to build an iOS app, which I'm working on using Xcode, on my iPhone but this morning when I tried to build and run the app, I get the error message below and cannot build the app now.

> Please check the connection to the device, and review all errors in
> the Devices and Simulators window.

I've already added my apple id in the account preferences and assigned the project to a team on the Signing & Capabilities pane of the project editor.

And this is the screenshot of the error in the Devices and Simulators window.
[image]
My Xcode version is 13.0 and iPhone is 14.7.1

I get the notification of "build succeed" but nothing shows up on my iPhone, so could anyone please tell me what should take a look at or what can I do next?

Comment: Quit and restart Xcode.  Turn your phone on and off.  Restart your Mac.  One of these will probably fix it.

Comment: @Paulw11 thank you so much for your response. I tried that but it did not work this time...

Comment: Try going in to Settings->Developer and "clear trusted computers" on your phone

Comment: If you go through using this way https://stackoverflow.com/a/71701826/13889070 you will get a proper solution to your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I deleted deriveddata and it worked.

Answer (score 9):

Following solution work for me

1. First check compatibility version for xcode with iOS version from following
   https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/
2. Now check the list of devices support to your Xcode from 'Device Support'
3. To get into 'Device Support' :: Open Finder -> Applications -> Scroll to Xcode -> Right Click -> Show Package Contents -> Contents -> Developer -> Platforms -> iPhoneOS.platform -> DeviceSupport
   This is the list of devices folder support for your Xcode
4. Now check for your iOS version from iPhone device :: Open Settings from iPhone -> General -> About -> Software Version
5. If the 'Device Support' folder does not contains the folder of your iPhone iOS Version, then you need to add respective folder from following link
   https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/tree/master/DeviceSupport
6. From above Github page, select device version & download zip file
7. Now extract file & you will get the folder for your iOS version
8. Copy this folder into Finder -> Applications -> Scroll to Xcode -> Right Click -> Show Package Contents -> Contents -> Developer -> Platforms -> iPhoneOS.platform -> DeviceSupport
9. Disconnect device (if connected), restart xcode
10. Before connecting device, delete derived data from xcode & clean cache using cmd + shft + k. Then make sure to reset 'Location & Privacy' from device :: From iPhone device go to Settings -> General -> Transfer or Rest Phone -> Reset -> Reset Location & Privacy -> Enter passcode to continue
11. Now connect your iPhone device with macbook (through cable), xcode will detect your device & you can run your application

Comment: Thanks this worked great for me for iOS 16.2! The latest in Contents -> Developer -> Platforms -> iPhoneOS.platform -> DeviceSupport was 16.1 but worked with the installed version of 16.2.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem today on my iPhone 12 Pro Max iOS 15.1 Xcode 13.1, restarts of the iPhone and Mac didn't help.

In the end I made sure that the paired Apple Watch was unlocked and trusted after that no more error and I was able to build to the iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

I was running the latest version of iOS v15.3.1  and after hours of pain I found that the solution was to update Xcode to the latest version

Answer (score 0):

Try the following operations，it works for me

1、deleted deriveddata
2、Turn off the phone and turn it on again

Comment: I followed the advice of @khirish but my folder DID contain the relevant iOS version.  I deleted derived data, cleaned xcode and restarted the phone and everything seemed to work.  Actually I also unpaired my apple watch. I have had more of these issues since pairing a watch in the last couple of months than I've had in about 3 years of development.

Answer (score 0):

iOS 15.6 beta:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/ios-ipados-release-notes/ios-ipados-15_6-release-notes

**Known Issues**

Xcode 13.4 is unable to prepare iOS 15.6 beta devices for development. (93452791)

**Workaround:** Use Xcode 13.3.1.

Comment: Workaround doesn't work at all ‍♂️