# "Failed to prepare device for development." with Xcode 13.2.1 and iOS 15.4 device

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm getting this message when I try to run an Xcode iOS project on my iPhone 8:

> This operation can fail if the version of the OS on the device is incompatible with the installed version of Xcode. You may also need to restart your mac and device in order to correctly detect compatibility.

I'm using Xcode 13.2.1 and iOS 15.4.

I've tried the different solutions given in other posts here on StackOverflow, but I haven't been able to fix the problem. [This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70734101/failed-to-prepare-device-for-development-xcode-13-2-1-ios-15-1) seems to be the latest identical question, just with previous versions of Xcode and iOS.

This post in this forums gives the solution to restart the iOS device and I did that and also restarted the mac. My Mac has macOS Monterey 12.3. My Xcode, Mac, and iPhone 8 all have the most recent updates. That post gives an answer for the same problem but with iOS 15.2.

I have recently changed settings in my iPhone 8 in Accessibility. Could that affect anything?

I found this error in the Xcode console for my device. Does this say anything about my problem?

> com.apple.analyticsd  xpc error   08:10:31.756711-0500    analyticsd  [XPC
> Server] managed connection recieved connection invalidated: Connection
> invalid

Comment: Restart you iPhone and it'll work just fine. Thanks

Comment: Restarting does not solve it in all cases

Answer (score 285):

1. Check /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/ for directory name 15.4 (your iOS version).
2. If the directory is missing download support files for 15.4 (your iOS version) from https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport and place it in the above path.
3. Restart Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for this, which sorted everything. Once I downloaded the 15.4.zip file from the link above, I unzipped it in the Downloads directory, then moved the 15.4 folder to the DeviceSupport directory. I did that with the help of this article: https://medium.com/@nayananp/how-to-add-device-support-files-to-xcode-4a7609b2f534. I then used 'chown' and 'xattr' to make everything the same as regards file groups and owners. Then shut down Xcode, my Mac, and my phone. Once I restarted everything and plugged my iPhone back into my Mac, I could finally recompile and see the app on the phone!

Comment: works like a charm. Its a generic fix which can be used to solve such incompatibilities in future aswell. Thankyou

Comment: It's help to me.

Comment: Great!! Solved it!! I needed iOS 15.5 and found it here: https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/tree/master/DeviceSupport

Comment: I'm stuck on MacOS 11.6.7 as I use an old MacBook Pro (Late 2013) so I can't get Xcode 13, but downloading the 15.4 support files fixed everything for me and I'm back up and running again on my new iPad 9th gen (with iOS 15.5)

I didn't need to do any chown-ing or xattr-ing, I just downloaded the 15.4 zip file, unzipped it, and moved it to the folder specified above and it all worked as soon as I started Xcode again.

Comment: why can't Apple provide a better error message and post a solution in their forum -- I know, I know, ... my question is rhetorical.

Comment: If this still doesn't work, restarting the phone like @stackich suggested will work... Cmon Apple...

Comment: If you are on iPhone iOS version 15.6 it is enough to download the zip version 16.0 - no need to change anything there.

Comment: I'm on 15.6 and downloading 16.0 did not work for me. I tried renaming it to '15.6' (another article I read suggested renaming for example 15.3.1 -> 15.3) but no success.

Comment: @GabrielJensen try 15.6 from here https://github.com/JinjunHan/iOSDeviceSupport

Comment: I wonder where these guys got the iOS zip files? I hope there's one single source of the truth

Comment: Why would you need to download that from some github repository? Isn't there a "official" mechanism in xcode to download those files?

Comment: Even if the files in your directory (for me, 15.6) are present, I replaced them with the ones from the GitHub repo, and it seems like this works for me!

Comment: I am trying for iOS 16.0.3 with iPhone 11 and Xcode 13.2.1 but not working.
If anyone can help it works.
I tried with 16.0 -> 16.0.3 rename as well but not working.

Comment: Getting this message in iOS 16.4.1 but can't seem to find the support files for these.

Comment: @JohnGorenfeld the file for 16.4 is there. You can find it right on the top of the readme file (as this is the current version). iOS 16.4 - https://github.com/filsv/iOSDeviceSupport/raw/master/16.4.zip

Comment: Ended up updating and it worked

Comment: @hannojg because Apple will force you to update Xcode to support the new iOS version (e.g. You need Xcode 14.3 to support iOS 16.4), but sometimes the latest Xcode version requires a new version of Mac OS (e.g. Xcode 14.3 requires macOS 13.0). Still, this version of macOS might not support our Macbook (e.g. macOS 13 doesn't support MBP 16). It looks stupid to buy a new MBP just to support development on new iOS version right? Let alone the f**king compatibility issue on new macOS and/or Xcode.

Comment: @AlbertZhong Same problem. I have a very old intel Mac and can't update Xcode to 14.3 since I can't upgrade to Mac 13.0. This is not compatible with my 16.4.1 iOS. I followed this answer but I'm unable to download iOS 16.4 files. It says 'Safari can't open page'. Is it accessible for others?

Comment: @NightFuryLxD try using the terminal "curl -OL https://github.com/filsv/iOSDeviceSupport/raw/master/16.4.zip"

Comment: @Simeon, Didn't work. Error - `curl: (28) Failed to connect to raw.githubusercontent.com port 443 after 75439 ms: Couldn't connect to server`.

Comment: @NightFuryLxD It seemed that you are behind a firewall or something that prevents you from connecting to github.com or githubusercontent.com. Try using a VPN, proxy, etc.

Comment: @AlbertZhong Probably. I asked my friend in a different network to download. Worked... thanks.

Comment: I had a beta OS on my iPad (16.6), downloaded the 16.5 release version into the directory and it worked, Thanks it I have been trying to find a solution for this for a a long time

Comment: my iphone is 16.6 and that's not available... KMN

Comment: I have 16.6 on my device and used the 16.4 download from github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/tree/master/DeviceSupport and it fixed it.

Comment: New to xCode and iOS here, i have the same issue(xCode 13.2.1 and iOS 17.2.1), but i can not find any folder of xCode, no /Applications/Xcode.app/.....Note that I installed xCode from a downloaded archive

Answer (score 63):

**Solution : Reboot iPhone.**

I have the latest version of :

- iOS
- Xcode

Still was not able to run the app on my device.

Solution that worked for me: **simple iPhone restart**

Comment: once again "Have you tried turning if off and on again?" saves the day. TY for reminding me ;)

Comment: just a simple restart of the ios worked for me too! :D

Comment: This is what worked for me. Embarrassed I didn't think of it first.

Comment: Lol such a shame. Indeed restarting my iPhone 11 Pro Max works!

Comment: I restarted my iphone and still didn't work :(

Comment: Same this happened for iPadOS. wow. 15.6.1. XCode Version 14.0.1 (14A400)

Comment: Incredible! lol This worked perfectly!

Comment: This does NOT always work. In fact, it's the first thing that Xcode tells you to do, and many people who are here right now are looking for an actual solution because the one presented to us isn't working.

Comment: doesn't work for me on Xcode 14.2 and iOS 16.4 :(

Answer (score 38):

Following solution work for me

1. First check compatibility version for xcode with iOS version from following https://developer.apple.com/support/xcode/
2. Now check the list of devices support to your Xcode from 'Device Support'
3. To get into 'Device Support' :: Open Finder -> Applications -> Scroll to Xcode -> Right Click -> Show Package Contents -> Contents -> Developer -> Platforms -> iPhoneOS.platform -> DeviceSupport This is the list of devices folder support for your Xcode
4. Now check for your iOS version from iPhone device :: Open Settings from iPhone -> General -> About -> Software Version
5. If the 'Device Support' folder does not contains the folder of your iPhone iOS Version, then you need to add respective folder from following link https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/tree/master/DeviceSupport
6. From above Github page, select device version & download zip file
7. Now extract file & you will get the folder for your iOS version
8. Copy this folder into Finder -> Applications -> Scroll to Xcode -> Right Click -> Show Package Contents -> Contents -> Developer -> Platforms -> iPhoneOS.platform -> DeviceSupport
9. Disconnect device (if connected), restart xcode
10. Before connecting device, delete derived data from xcode & clean cache using cmd + shft + k. Then make sure to reset 'Location & Privacy' from device :: From iPhone device go to Settings -> General -> Transfer or Rest Phone -> Reset -> Reset Location & Privacy -> Enter passcode to continue
11. Now connect your iPhone device with macbook (through cable), xcode will detect your device & you can run your application

https://stackoverflow.com/a/72143610/15716725

Answer (score 18):

for Xcode 13.2.1, and running on the device with iOS version 15.5
https://github.com/filsv/iOSDeviceSupport/blob/master/15.5.zip
download this zip and extract it into

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/ for directory name 15.5 (your iOS version).

and restart the xocode

[image]

Comment: Huh, you could have been my man with this but unfortunately there's no runtime for 15.8 there since November 2023, they stopped at 15.7. I hope the guy behind this Github page didn't die in covid.

Answer (score 10):

I installed iOS 16.0 beta and faced this message on Xcode.

> This operation can fail if the version of the OS on the device is
> incompatible with the installed version of Xcode.

In my case, I enabled developer mode on the device, and it worked.

You can follow this path for activating developer mode on your iOS device.

> Settings > Privacy & Security > Developer Mode

Answer (score 5):

For all of you having problem with iOS 15.7 on device. Apple is aware of it.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-14-release-notes

> Xcode 14 cannot be used with iOS 15.7 for development. (99847608)

There is workaround for it

> Workaround: Use Xcode 13.4.1 with iOS 15.7.

Comment: That’s a massive mistake by Apple

Comment: You no longer have to: xcode 14.0.1 works with 15.7 Sometimes after iOS device reboot ;^)

Answer (score 3):

> I'm using Xcode 13.2.1 and iOS 15.4 on my iPhone 8

That's the problem. Your Xcode is incompatible with your iPhone system. Update to Xcode 13.3.

> My Xcode, Mac, and iPhone 8 all have the most recent updates

No, they don't.

Answer (score 2):

Dowloading latest xcode beta version was the only solution for me:

https://developer.apple.com/download/all/

Answer (score 2):

### Previous fix (non-working)

[The workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71667372/13906110) from @Simeon is not working any more for iOS versions above 16.0

I would like Apple to do its job and create a stable fix. Apparently, they are entitled to make more money, not great pieces of software anymore.

### Current fix

In order to fix this, the easiest (but clearly not the fastest nor the most efficient) is to delete and reinstall Xcode or its beta.

### Assumptions

The issue essentially comes from the fact that one folder is missing in order to run later versions of iOS, and Xcode is not fetching them for i-don't-know what reasons.

[image: All pieces of software and OS are up-to-date]
As you can see in the screenshot above, all pieces of software and OS are up-to-date.

[image: The folder for iOS 16.4 is missing.]

Nevertheless, the folder for iOS 16.4 is still missing.

Comment: You can find the device support for 16.4 if you download the RC3 from the developer website and extract its contents. That's what I just did.

Comment: You may need to get the latest XCode 14.3 in order to have 16.4. Otherwise need to find related files from github shared by community.

Comment: U need to update XCode. It saved me.

Comment: @ThomasLee I have updated to XCode 14.2. Yet there are no 16.x directories under iOS. GitHub has only till 16.5, but my iPhone 8+ has iOS 16.7. I moved the contents of GitHuB 16.5 under a folder named 16.7 and placed it under DeviceSupport. It solved my problem instantly. While Apple painfully installs all the Jurrassic Park versions of iOS under Device Support, it's strange that it chose to ignore the latest versions. In fact, I did a fresh XCode 14.2 download and installed it yesterday only. Still, it didn't have any folders for iOS 16.x.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when upgraded my phone to ios 16.4. When I opened Window -> Devices and Simulators this message was displayed. As others have mentioned upgrading xcode made it work again:

```
Failed to prepare the device for development.
This operation can fail if the version of the OS on the device is incompatible with the installed version of Xcode. You may also need to restart your Mac and device in order to correctly detect compatibility.
```

The App Store app did not show any updates, I had to search for xcode to see an update-button, no automagic in this case.

Answer (score 1):

My iPhone was `15.5`, and I checked `/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport`, there is no such `15.5`, then I noticed update notification for Xcode in AppStore, which is said `Version 13.4.1 - Xcode 13.4.1 includes SDKs for iOS 15.5, ...`, then I just need to execute Xcode update

Answer (score 1):

I actually downloaded the 15.5 version and renamed it as 15.6, I have also done this before when I was using the iOS 11.*** version, it worked in few of the cases.

Answer (score 1):

Apple has addressed this issue. See the following thread with a link to the Xcode 14.0.1 Release Candidate. Open the .xip file and then the run Xcode.app within. I was able to build my app on a device with iOS 15.7. I believe you have to be a paid Apple Developer to open the link.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/714388

Answer (score 1):

For those with an issue relating to XCode 15 and iOS 17 as a result of the various beta issues with trusting devices and the duplicate notification [Known Issue (109539668)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode-release-notes/xcode-15-release-notes#:%7E:text=Devices%20running%20iOS%2017%20may%20prompt%20the%20user%20twice%20in%20rapid%20succession%20to%20trust%20a%20Mac%20when%20connected%20to%20the%20Mac%20with%20a%20USB%20cable.%20The%20second%20prompt%20for%20trust%20may%20obscure%20the%20first%20prompt%20and%20prevent%20the%20user%20from%20entering%20the%20passcode.%20(109539668)). This issue results in getting stuck in the same place "Previous preparation error: The tunnel connection failed while the system tried to connect to the device.. The tunnel connection failed while the system tried to connect to the device.".

I was hopeful that the final release of each of these would be the end of the  issue. Alas it was not. I reset my iPad completely, Settings -> General -> Transfer or Reset iPad -> Reset (a total pain I know) and both the duped notification and connection issues with mac are resolved.

Answer (score 1):

For the 15.8 version of iOS not working, use this solution: https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/issues/237.

After you go here (as mentionned in the other answers): Open Finder -> Applications -> Scroll to Xcode -> Right Click -> Show Package Contents -> Contents -> Developer -> Platforms -> iPhoneOS.platform -> DeviceSupport This is the list of devices folder support for your Xcode

Copy the 15.5 folder and rename it 15.8.

Reboot XCode, unplug and replug the phone, and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

> I had the same problem so i had to update xcode to the latest version

**Issue**

xcode version was 14.0.1 - which supported iOS 16.0 (20A360), but my iphone is having 16.3.1 version.

**Solution**

Updated Xcode with 14.3

Answer (score 0):

My case is likely fringe/rare but in case it helps anyone:

- **I was getting this annoying "Failed to prepare device for development" error for my iPad 12.9 iOS 16.4.1 in Xcode 14.2** (as of 1/28/24)
- None of the delete derrived data, reboots, etc above fixes worked
- I downloaded the 16.4 zip from [this site](https://github.com/filsv/iOSDeviceSupport/tree/master) (mentioned above):
- I extracted to here as a folder named "16.4" /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport
- However it still did not work / gave same error
- I then ***renamed the 16.4 folder to "16.4.1', unpaired and retried ... then the error finally went away*** and I can use my iPad for testing local builds again

Answer (score -1):

Following the solution of:

Adding the folder the iOS version to the path of XCode:

/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/

[image]

I had the problem for iOS 16.6 and I couldn't find it at https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport at the moment, so I found this other repo with the lastest versions https://github.com/JinjunHan/iOSDeviceSupport

After restarting my phone and xCode it works.