# How to build for iOS 15.4.1 with a 2014 Macbook?

Tags: ios, xcode, macos

The latest iOS version, 15.4.1, is no longer compatible with Xcode 13.2.

However, Xcode 13.3 is not compatible with OSX Big Sur.

However, 2014 Macbooks are not compatible with Monterey.

Is there any way to build targeting my iPhone on iOS 15.4.1 without buying a new Mac? Is there a workaround at any of these steps?

One workaround is to build an Archive, deploy to TestFlight, then download on iOS. This is not sustainable, but shows that a 2014 Macbook is **capable** of building for my device, it's just a question of whether Apple will allow it.

Comment: "Is there any way to build targeting my iPhone on iOS 15.4.1 without buying a new Mac" Well, there's borrowing a new Mac, stealing a new Mac... Seriously, this is just how life is. Apple ups the requirements and eventually if you want to keep developing you have to up your hardware. We all do it.

Comment: Are you suggesting there is not a workaround, or that there may be a workaround but I should not look for one because "that's how life is"?

Comment: No, I'm not suggesting either of those.

Comment: You cannot build targetting iOS 15. You might target a lower iOS version and still install the app on your device. However, you won't be able to use any iOS 15 functionality and you won't be able to create a production build for app store.
Get a new mac. The cheapest mac air is not very expensive and it will be drastically faster than your 8 years old mac.

Comment: This solution has worked for me on Mac Mid 2014. https://stackoverflow.com/a/71667372