# The run destination xxxx iPhone is not valid for Running the scheme 'Unity-iPhone'

Tags: xcode, unity-game-engine

When uploading my Unity-IOS-app I suddenly have been running into this in Xcode:

> **The run destination xxxx iPhone is not valid for Running the scheme 'Unity-iPhone'.**
> Failed to prepare the device for development. This operation can fail if the version of the OS on the device is incompatible with the installed version of Xcode. You may also need to restart your Mac and device in order to correctly detect compatibility.

I have ofc been googling this but not been able to fix the problem. I also do not understand why it suddenly appeared.

Among other things I have done the following:

- Patched up Unity to latest 2022.2.8f1
- Updated my Mac to Ventura
- Changed lowest IOS from 15 to 13 In Xcode
- Googled and tried most of the things I have found

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Failed to prepare device for development." with Xcode 13.2.1 and iOS 15.4 device](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71618452/failed-to-prepare-device-for-development-with-xcode-13-2-1-and-ios-15-4-devic)

Answer (score -1):

Unbelievable, I have been testing so many things but failed to restart my iPhone, which solved this problem, as described [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71618452/failed-to-prepare-device-for-development-with-xcode-13-2-1-and-ios-15-4-devic/71667372#71667372).

Comment: Thank you! One may wonder why it is never acceptable here to realise you done a mistake!