# Xcode 13.2.1 error when running on phone with iOS 15.4.1

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I had to update the iOS on my iPhone so I upgraded it to the latest version. This forced me to have to update my Xcode as well. It upgraded to 13.2.1 because I guess my computer OS isn't the most recent (a couple months behind). Now, I'm getting the below error:

```
Failed to prepare device for development.

This operation can fail if the version of the OS on the device is incompatible with the installed version of Xcode. You may also need to restart your mac and device in order to correctly detect compatibility.
```

Not sure how to fix this. Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

There is solution if you can’t (or don’t want for now) update Xcode for some reason.

For example I have Xcode 13.2.1, and iPhone with latest iOS 15.5. So this version of Xcode don’t support this iOS version.

For solution you can go [here](https://github.com/mspvirajpatel/Xcode_Developer_Disk_Images/releases), and code and download files for your current iOS version you needed (according to your device version).

Next do these three steps to add the file in Xcode:

– 1. Go to Applications > Right click on Xcode and Select Show Package Contents > Contents > Developer > Platforms > iPhoneOS.platform > DeviceSupport.

– 2. Extract your device support file to DeviceSupport Folder.

– 3. Restart Xcode and unplug and plug in your device.

(find this solution from post of this kind man - [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71701826/19373604))

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at https://xcodereleases.com. Xcode 13.2.1 supports **up-to** iOS 15.2. Upgrading to the latest Xcode (13.3.1) will fix the issue.

Conversely, you can take the less conventional route https://medium.com/naukri-engineering/how-to-support-latest-ios-devices-with-older-xcode-versions-22c087b024e6