# xcode 13.4.1 compatible with ios 15.5?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode13

I am getting the XCode error that typically means that the XCode version is too old to connect to a given Ios version but this is the latest released XCode version 13.4.

Failed to prepare device for development.
Restarting does not help and if anything, further updates to iOS will probably make it worse.  Are there other fixes? (Other than restarting the phone)

[image]

RElated:  Restarting phone:
[Xcode error: Failed to prepare device for development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64974291/xcode-error-failed-to-prepare-device-for-development)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's compatible:

- on my MacBook Xcode 13.4 can build apps for my iPhone SE 2 which is on iOS 15.5,
- on [xcodereleases.com](https://xcodereleases.com/) we can read that in Xcode 13.4 the iOS 15.5 SDK is available.

Earlier I noticed that with one of my cables the above mentioned error message popped up all the time. Once I change the cable the problem disappeared. But this is not a solution for everyone of course; I just say that this problem can have multiple reasons, which I think cannot be guessed based on your description.

Comment: Yeah, I rebooted both mac and phone twice and now it's gone, so I'm deleting question